# Inverse Gaussian and normal-inverse Gaussian distributions synonymous

Tags: distributions, terminology

On Wikipedia, there is a page for the [inverse Gaussian distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Gaussian_distribution) and the [normal-inverse Gaussian distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal-inverse_Gaussian_distribution). And I observed some confusion in other websites: they say normal-inverse Gaussian instead of inverse Gaussian. So I'm wondering whether there are other names. The name *Wald distribution* is proposed at some places but again there's the same confusion: some use it for the IG, others use it for the NIG. Are there other names to dissipate this possible confusion?